# a floating point precision of X

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not a code revision, therefore I have created the thread here. I have an assignment which is as follows:

> Write a program which:
>   1. intializes a variable a with 123, and prints the value of a over 7 places,
>   2. intializes a variable b with -89.6548754, and prints the value of b over 10 places and 
>   with a floating point precision of 4

The first one is:

```
a = 123
print("The value is {0:7d}".format(a))
```

What I do not understand is the second one. What is "a floating point precision of 4"? What does it mean? I guess it means shortening the number of decimals (which is 7 (6548754)) to 4.

```
b=-89.6548754
print("The value is {:10.4f}".format(b))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [format string mini-language specification](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should
>   be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value
>   formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point
>   for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`. For
>   non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other
>   words, how many characters will be used from the field content. The
>   *precision* is not allowed for integer values.

So yes, it is the number of digits after the decimal point.