# Initialize a variable c with ’b’

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment about which I am pretty confused.

> Write a program which:
>   (1.) intializes a variable a with 123, and prints the value of a over 7 places
>   (2.) intializes a variable b with -89.6548754, and prints the value of b over 10 places and with a floating point precision of 4
>   (3.) initializes a variable c with ’b’, and prints the character on the screen

I got the first two, which are as follows
First:

```
a = 123
print("The value is {0:7d}".format(a))
```

and the second one is:

```
b=-89.6548754
print("The value is {:10.4f}".format(b))
```

But does the third one mean? My problem is with the English of the question. Is the one below what the assignment question is about?

```
c='b'
print(c)
```

Comment: your classmate was confused too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027040/a-floating-point-precision-of-x

Comment: If you don't understand the question, or suspect it meant to ask something else, ask the person who asked it to clarify

Comment: You are right but at least you could guess what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe that you understood what the text says precisely.

**(3.) initializes a variable c with ’b’, and prints the character on the screen**

It clearly, tells you to start this variable with a single char, and then print it on the screen and thats what you did.

However, since your question isn't really about code I believe this question was placed on the wrong forum, it would be better to post it here:

https://english.stackexchange.com/

It is an specific forum about English and as such the meaning of an assignment would fit perfectly there.

Comment: Thanks! It is inconsistent with the question. The assignment is about formatting but the third one is about defining a variable. Very strange to me.

Comment: @Rakanoth, you didn't told the assignment was about formating, but even then a lot of teachers/professors that I know give tricky questions that aren't hard but are there just for bugging with your mind. I've got once a teacher who gave me an impossible sequence to be done in python and the answer he expected was: *it's not possible*. Good lucky with your studies!